# When to Load Custom CSS in MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

When my website loads depending on the URL there are a few   CSS files that need to be loaded.

1. bootstrap-rtl
2. 3 differenct Custom CSS files

The challenge is that for a split second the "original bootstrap" gets loaded (ltr) and navbar showing the base bootstrap button colors

I have a  shared _Layout and I link to the rtl and custom css before the regular "Links"

Website can be viewed at https://www.ctp.co.il/dashboard/galil-test

What am I doing wrong?

Regards

M.R.

Comment: Your link gives me a HTTP 404 error.

Comment: How are you "loading" these custom CSS files? What do you mean by "MVC" in this context? (you haven't tagged your question with "ASP.NET MVC" specifically and there are many other MVC frameworks for other languages around).

Comment: oops yes the site is https://www.ctp.co.il/Dashboard/galil-test

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider custom view engine? The concept is to have the theme loaded dynamically. If your layout files are the same and only CSS files are different (ltr or rtl) then by utilizing the view engine you can load the CSS files that are requirted.

Before the page load your theme engine would determine which CSS to load and only load that CSS. Not all CSS files. So your few seconds flicker would not be there.

In your case your theme may contin only CSS files. But in the future you may include content and views based on themes.

Here is a detail implementation of a view engine in MVC: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32847/ASP-NET-MVC-Dynamic-Themes